# A block falling from a height on a block suspended by spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, collision, spring

The block suspended by the spring is hanging freely and its mass is M.
The small block of mass m is dropped on the bigger block from height h. [image]

After the small block is dropped 》》》
[image]

I want help in analysis using simple harmonic motion.
Find frequency, amplitude and shm equation. I want help in analysing this problem using simple harmonic motion.

Thank u for giving me a -1 post when im being specific with my problem. Ive been trying to do this for a long time. Instead of help I get a negative vote thank u so much.......

Comment: I posted a similar problem before. I was asked to be more specific. When I'm specific I get -1 vote thank u so much !!!!!!

Comment: Maybe you need to ask about a specific physics concept, and not ask for help solving a specific problem for you. See http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/715/392

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initial conditions do not matter with simple harmonic motion. The oscillating frequency is going to be found from the combined mass $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{M+m}}$

To get the amplitude you take the general solution of $y(t) = y_0 + Y \sin \omega t$ and use it in the equations of motion $m \ddot{y} = (M+m) g- k\, y$ and solve for $Y$ and $y_0$ for all times $t$.

A simplified example would be, if you had $(1-A) \sin \omega t + (2-B) \cos \omega=0$, then the solution would only be $A=1\;B=2$, since all other values would not solve the equation for *all* values of $t$.

**PS.** I hope you have had calculus and differential equations, which are a pre-requisite for harmonic motion and vibrations.